# KOMA-script: Write "Appendix" in the table of contents

Tags: koma-script

I have

```
\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}}
```

from the KOMA-script p. 517, causes the word "Appendix" to appear before the sections in the appendix.

*How do I achieve this in the TOC?*

```
1. A Section
Appendix A. A Section in the Appendix
            A.1. A Subsection in the Appendix 
Appendix B. Another Section in the Appendix
```

**MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents   
 \section{A Section} ...
 \appendix       
\section{A Section in the Appendix} ...
\subsection{A Subsection in the Appendix} ...
\section{Another Section in the Appendix} ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Since KOMA-Script version 3.31 option `dynindent` can be used in the optional argument of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries`:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}[2020/07/22]% needs version 3.31 or newer
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\useprefix[2]{#1#2}

\NewDocumentCommand\appendixprefixintoc{}
{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
    [%
      entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\appendixname~},% add the prefix before the entrynumber
      dynnumwidth
    ]{default}{section}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    dynindent
  ]{default}{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixprefixintoc}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get the same result as in my original answer (see below).

---

**Original answer:**
Here is a suggestion that needs KOMA-Script version 3.27 or newer:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}[2019/10/13]% needs version 3.27 or newer
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\useprefix[2]{#1#2}
\newlength\appendixprefixwidth

\NewDocumentCommand\appendixprefixintoc{}
{%
  \setlength\appendixprefixwidth{%
    \widthof{\usekomafont{sectionentry}\appendixname~}}% measure needed additional space
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
    [%
      entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\appendixname~},% add the prefix before the entrynumber
      numwidth+=\appendixprefixwidth% enlarge numwidth for level section
    ]{default}{section}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    indent+=\appendixprefixwidth% enlarge indent for other levels
  ]{default}{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixprefixintoc}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! ....................

Comment: How do I make it work for `scrreport`? I get the error `Package scrkbase Error: font of element `sectionentry' can't be used. \appendixprefixintoc`

Comment: @homocomputeris With `scrreprt` the appendices are chapters. `scrreprt` does not provide the elment `sectionentry` but `chapterentry`. You can also ask a new question including a MWE for `scrreprt`.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\setappendixprefix{}
{% 
 \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\appendixname~,dynnumwidth=true]{default}{section}
}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
   \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
      \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
   \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
      \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
   \addtocontents{toc}{\setappendixprefix}
   }


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
 \section{A Section} ...
 \appendix
\section{A Section in the Appendix} ...
\subsection{A Subsection in the Appendix} ...
\section{Another Section in the Appendix} ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, ok.    I think, there is a problem with "A.1. ..." this should appear in under "A Section...", like the other toc-entries.  I wrote down my ilustration wrong.         

 `1. A Section
    Appendix A. A Section in the Appendix
                A.1. A Subsection in the Appendix 
    Appendix B. Another Section in the Appendix`

Answer (score 0):

The add "Appendix" to chapters instead:

```latex
\newcommand\useprefix[2]{#1#2}

\NewDocumentCommand\appendixprefixintoc{}
{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
    [%
      entrynumberformat=\useprefix{\appendixname~},% add the prefix before the entrynumber
      dynnumwidth
    ]{default}{chapter}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    dynindent
  ]{default}{chapter,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixprefixintoc}%
}
```